# mongodb $sum only postive Numbers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

is their a way i can sum only positive numbers and avoid those with negative in my MongoDB aggregate query i.e

```
aggregate([
      {
        $match: { },
      },
      { $group: { _id: '$id',  total: { $sum: '$amount' } } },
    ])
```

Comment: You could match documents only where the amount is positive: `$match: { amount: { $gte: 0 } }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator and simply `$sum` `0` when the number is negative:

```
{ $group: { _id: '$id',  total: { $sum: { $cond: [ { $gt: [ '$amount', 0 ] }, '$amount', 0 ]  } } } }
```